# Install Gitlab CE in a GCP instance VM ubuntu 18.04

Tags: exception, google-cloud-platform, timezone, ubuntu-18.04, gitlab-ce

This is my first time trying to install Gitlab CE in a Google Cloud Platform instanceVM. I have followed two different ways to do that, the official one:

[Ubuntu installation](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu)

and the one from this tutorial:

[How to install gitlab](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-gitlab-10-5-7-on-ubuntu-18-04).

However, in both cases I've got the same error:

```
bash
Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 55) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200523-23121-djcfhu" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: No source of timezone data could be found.
Please refer to https://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
TZInfo::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200523-23121-djcfhu" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200523-23121-djcfhu" returned 1
```

I have actually followed the link provided by the output [Datasource not found](https://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound) but does talk about Ruby on Rails and I'm not using it. So, does anyone knows how to fix this **ZoneInfo** error in a GCP instance? Or how to let GitLab to ignore it.

Any kind of help will be useful :)

Thanks you all!

Btw, I'm using the bionic's gitlab-ce_13.0.0-ce.0_amd64.deb version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i have just noticed that I was using the minimal version of Ubuntu Bionic. With the classical one gets fixed.